# Linux Nemo File Manager extension development in Kotlin Native

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kotlin-native

I'm have a few ideas for extensions for `Nemo` and other Linux File Managers I want to develop like for example a properties extension and much more.

How are the extensions actually compiled? Are they `Shared Objects` or `SO`s?

https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/

If they are shared objects and since they use C code, does that mean I can make an extension using Kotlin Native, since Kotlin Native can now compile to SO?

If the extensions are not compiled to SO, is there a way to make extensions using Kotlin Native? I'm guessing not.

I can't code in any other language, but am curious if it is possible to make Nemo extensions using any language that can compile to SO.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to turn Kotlin/Native code into an `SO`, aka dynamic library. You may have a look at the related tutorial https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/dynamic-libraries.html